# Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""

Tags: android, float, java

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть вот такое вычисление и все считается правильно. 
Но если строка `etPrice` не заполнена, выдает ошибку. Как можно проверить строку etPrice на ее пустоту, чтобы возвратить пользователя к ее заполнению?

```
long hoursDays = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
float priceHour = Float.valueOf(etPrice.getText().toString());
float result1 = priceHour / 24;
Math.ceil(priceHour);
float result = result1 * hoursDays;
tvSumma.setText(result + " руб.");
tvInfo2.setText(days + " день " + hours + " часов " + minutes
    + " минут");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть метод
java.lang.String.isEmpty()

Comment: А можно немного подробнее, я только учусь :(

Comment: isEmpty() возвращает true если строка пустая, и false в противоположном случае.
Добавляете куда вам нужно проверку:
if(etPrice.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
    //
}

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось

Answer (score 0):

Помимо проверки на пустоту, ещё было бы неплохо проверить строку на null.

```
String str = etPrice.getText().toString();
if(str == null || str.isEmpty()){
    //some default value
}
```

Если строка равна `null`, то метод `isEmpty()` этот случай не обработает, а выдаст `NullPointerException`.